# Is there any conflict between AngularJS and jQuery(UI)?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

I try to make the items of a list draggable, but it doesn't work. jQuery doesn't seem to add the **ui-draggable** class, or maybe Angular removes it.

### Javascript

```
$('.results_video').draggable({
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="results_video" ng-repeat="video in results.list">
  {{video.title}}
</div>
```

Note that if I just write the following html, it works

```
<div class="results_video"></div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the browser console report any errors?

Comment: hmm...maybe the node isn't in the DOM at the time jQuery is polling it? Is the node with the `.results_video` class loaded dynamically? Also, is the JavaScript code run immediately or on DOM ready?

Comment: @War10ck This is what it is. jQuery UI tries to enable the draggable behaviour on the elements it finds on the page when it runs. This is incompatible with ng-repeat, which produces a dynamic list of elements that may be added and removed after the jQuery UI code has run. In a similar situation I had to define a custom Angular directive which enabled the behaviour on elements whenever they were added to the page, and properly deactivated them when they were removed. Unfortunately, I don't have such code handy to post.

Comment: @JeremyBanks That makes sense. I was figuring the content was dynamically loaded or created and therefore jQueryUI couldn't attach properly. Sorry I'm just getting started with Angularjs. I missed the `ng-repeat`. That makes complete sense now though. So basically the custom Angular directive will bind/unbind the _draggable_ event as appropriate for each item as its added/removed from the DOM? Is that the idea?

Comment: @War10ck Yup, that's what's necessary if you want the proper integration between Angular and stuff like jQuery UI. Practically, if you're not really going to be modifying the content of the list you can just make sure that jQuery UI runs after the elements are initially populated, but that feels gross.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I got ya. Binding after the list is created does sound like a way to fix it but I have to agree, it seems like it would make for a nasty little code base. That makes complete sense. Thanks buddy. I appreciate you explaining that to me. :)

Comment: Even if I execute the following code in the console after the page has been loaded, it doesn't work: $(".results_video").addClass("ui-draggable")

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I need to make these divs draggable **after** they have been loaded. In my case:

```
var VideoCtrl = function ($scope){
  $scope.$watch('search', function(){
    //Some code that updates the divs
    $('.results_video').draggable();
  });
};
```